# Can't report a bug in the Android app from the Android app itself

Tags: bug, android-app

(App version 1.0.2)

The Help screen says bugs should be reported on Meta Stack Overflow (with a link). However, when I click on the link, then select the "Q" icon in the action bar, and it asks "Ask on which site?"*, Meta Stack Overflow is not in the list and no results come up when I type the name.

*which is weird, because I'm already in Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: It's an old report, but anyway, not repro'd on SE app v1.0.82 (beta). Both MSO and MSE are available and selectable.

Answer (score 1):

I can ask meta.so questions in the app. [[proof](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217691/171881)]. Okay this was posted with 1.0.1 but in 1.0.2 I have the same options and I can ask questions.

Comment: I just attempted to post a new question on meta and it was selected by default for me.

Comment: Me too. The app just wanted to show my last already posted question. Possible another bug.

Answer (score 1):

I can ask questions on Meta using the Android App.  It seemed to quite natural to start the process.

FWIW, it was a pain to finish the process - the message about which tags you have to have is cumbersome, and waiting 60 seconds every time you make a mistake is a pain.   After being rejected for not having one of the critical tags, my post was then rejected for not meeting some unexplained criteria, which was only solved by adding more (superfluous) text to the question.   All in all, I suspect I'll only be using the app to ask questions to get hats, in the future :)