# Android app posts bugs as a post in meta

Tags: feature-request, android-app

This is to say the least, unexpected behaviour.

Given that one is expected to post questions on meta, which adhere to certain guidelines. The fact that the app posts directly to meta rather than a jira is bad/surprising behaviour.

There is no prompt for a search of dupes like in a standard question post, nor are possible dupes displayed.

If someone marks this as a dupe, that would rather prove my point...

Can the screen be changed to make it clear what will happen and, ideally, include a dupe search?

Comment: We don't have a bug tracker other than meta. I don't know what this looks like in the app (iOS here :)), but it sounds like we could do something to make it clearer what's going to happen. I'm retagging this to a feature-request.

Answer (score 3):

You could say the same about the question dialog generally.

In fact, "submit the bug report" provides you with exactly the same dialog which you get when click "Q" icon in the top bar, and so it does explicitly state what site you're going to post on (nothing surprising I mean).

About the dupes: preceding the "submit the bug report" button, there's an option to view existing bugs and requests. Yes, not that convenient, but at least something providing you with an ability to search first. (These friendly "controls" over the bug reporting first introduced [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277405).)

Answer (score 2):

It is already clear enough in my opinion:

> [image]

I really can't see any need to clarify it any further. Those links are just shortcuts to posting on MSE, pre-filling things for you to make it easier to report. And the big "Existing bug reports and feature requests" is exactly what you asked for in by "include a dupe search".